# How to publish an app internally for users of my organisation and not publicly?

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, developer-program

I want to build and deploy an iOS app only for my company specific users.

I do not want to publish it for normal users on the iOS App Store. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).

This program, created specifically with the said need in mind lets you distribute and manage apps internally in your organization, without going through public faing iOS App Store.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick and easy solution and are familiar with generating .ipa files (ad-hoc deployment), you can use Diawi for deploying it on the specific devices. Please keep in mind that the device-UDIDs need to be registered in your apple developer account. 
https://www.diawi.com/
(apps can be password protected aswell)

Comment: Can i use it as a permanent deployment solution for my enterprise.?

Comment: The diawi deployment link will be available for 3 days if you are a using a free account. The .ipa itself will be valid as long as your provisional profile is working (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802976/does-the-generated-ipa-expires)
If you are looking for a pure permanent solution you should probably stick to Nimesh Neema's solution.